# AngularJs Bootstrap pagination using ng-repeat not working properly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap pagination on ng-repeat.

**HTML**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="userDetails in data.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) |filter:status:status.status" >   
      <td>{{userDetails.status.status}}</td>
      <td> {{ userDetails.subDate | date : 'MM-dd-yyyy' }} </td>
      <td> {{ userDetails.fullName }} </td>
      <td> {{ userDetails.serviceType.serviceName }} </td>
      <td> {{ userDetails.status.status }} </td>
 </tr>
<select ng-model="viewby" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)"><option>5</option><option>10</option></select> records at a time.

<uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></uib-pagination>
```

**JS**

```
$http.get('getAlldetails').success(function(response)
    {
        $scope.data = response;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.data.length;
        $scope.viewby = 10;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
        $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show

        $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
            $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
            $scope.currentPage = 1; 
            }               
    })
```

Problem is if I set 10 items per page, it shows random number of items like 7 items in first page, 9 items in next page and goes on. I tried with adding ui-bootstrap-tpls.js too but no luck.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution suggested below?

Answer (score 3):

You are see seeing those results because the paging is being applied before the filtering. So for page size 10, 10 items are selected, then the filter runs leaving 7 or 9 items or however many of those 10 satisfy the filter.

This can be fixed by rearranging your ng-repeat code like this, to ensure that the filter is applied first:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="userDetails in (data | filter:status:status.status).slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) " >
```